# What SDK's Are Available for App Uninstall Analytics

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, analytics, uninstallation

GooglePlay developer console provides simple uninstall stats breakdown by device, country, version, device etc. But this isn't enough. I'm looking for an SDK / product that would provide:

1. Uninstalls by number of days used, as in how many uninstalled on 1st day, how many on 2nd, 3rd, etc.
2. What screens user visited?
3. What was the last screen user visited / last action taken?
4. What country was the user in when uninstall occurred (not the country where user is from) ?
5. Attribution to AdWords campaign or organic downloads

What SDKs / products are available for App Uninstall Analytics that would answer some, all or most of the above points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start) will provide you most the above points that you mentioned in your question.